# Why does fluent.validate throw an exception in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

i want to override the default asp.net-mvc validation when posting a form [so i tried using fluent.validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc)

i created a validator class (ProjectValidator)

```
public class ProjectValidator : AbstractValidator<Project>
{
    public ProjectValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(h => h.Application).NotNull().WithName("Application");
        RuleFor(h => h.FundingType).NotNull().WithName("Funding Type");
        RuleFor(h => h.Description).NotEmpty().WithName("Description");
        RuleFor(h => h.Name).NotEmpty().WithName("Project Name");
    }
}
```

i put an attribute on my Data Transfer Object class

```
[Validator(typeof(ProjectValidator))]
  public class ProjectViewModel
  {
      ...
  }
```

and i put this in application_start();

```
 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
            .AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

 ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
            new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory()));
```

but when i post a form that uses this object, i get the following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 FluentValidation.IValidatorDescriptor.GetValidatorsForMember(System.String)'.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem related to the assembly versions you are using. Here are the steps that work for me with the latest version of FluentValidation.NET and ASP.NET MVC 3:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default Visual Studio template.
2. Install the `FluentValidation.MVC3` NuGet package.
3. Add the view model and its corresponding validator (notice that in your case you have the validator for type **Project** - `AbstractValidator<Project>` whereas your view model is called `ProjectViewModel` which is inconsistent. The validator must be associated to the view model):

   ```
   public class ProjectValidator : AbstractValidator<ProjectViewModel>
   {
       public ProjectValidator()
       {
           RuleFor(h => h.Application).NotNull().WithName("Application");
           RuleFor(h => h.FundingType).NotNull().WithName("Funding Type");
           RuleFor(h => h.Description).NotEmpty().WithName("Description");
           RuleFor(h => h.Name).NotEmpty().WithName("Project Name");
       }
   }

   [Validator(typeof(ProjectValidator))]
   public class ProjectViewModel
   {
       public string Application { get; set; }
       public string FundingType { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. In `Application_Start` register the validator:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

       RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

       DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
       ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory()));
   }
   ```
5. Define a controller:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View(new ProjectViewModel());
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Index(ProjectViewModel model)
       {
           return View(model);
       }
   }
   ```
6. And a view:

   ```
   @model Appame.Models.ProjectViewModel

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       <div>
           @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Application)
           @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Application)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Application)
       </div>
       <div>
           @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FundingType)
           @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FundingType)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FundingType)
       </div>
       <div>
           @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)
           @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
       </div>
       <div>
           @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
           @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
       </div>

       <input type="submit" value="OK" />
   }
   ```